# Not able to run test case on Simulator using jenkins on MAC

Tags: xcode, jenkins, ios-simulator, macos-sierra

I am getting below error while running XCTest test cases on simulator on jenkins:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10810.)

It happening because Jenkins run as daemon. So, I did all changes as mentioned in [this link](http://www.cimgf.com/2015/05/26/setting-up-jenkins-ci-on-a-mac-2/) to make it starting at boot time itself.

But still after doing all the changes, Jenkins process does not start after reboot.

Also checked the owner for `/var/log/Jenkins/Jenkins.log` and it is correct.

NB: MAC OS - Seirra 10.12.3

Comment: I strongly feel jenkins is running (*try to check node status from server dashboard and try to execute simple command on jenkin slave to verify*). Please verify if **SIMULATOR** is running while running test or not before executing XCTest from Jenkins

Comment: Could you show the command you use to run the tests?

Comment: @SACHIN Both are running when  i try to execute the test case.

Answer (score 0):

So because you didn't specify your setup exactly I'm going to need to give an answer based on a guess regarding your setup.

I think you are using the [xcode plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin) with Jenkins to execute everything related to your xcode project

So when you go to your job under the `build` tab you will have the `xcode plugin`

open the `Advanced xcode build options` tab en navigate to `custom xcodebuild arguments`

In here we will tell the plugin what it needs to run in your case you want tests to run. For this we will use

`test -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=<yourID>'`

which will tell the plugin on which platform it should run the tests and which ID of the emulator it needs to know.

In order to retrieve the correct id open up your terminal and run the command

`xcrun simctl list`
which will return you a list of all the simulators. Pick your desired device and grab the ID of it. put this in the spot of `<yourID>`

[image]

so it will look like this

`test -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=FEF05FDC-56BD-48B9-BDFD-210CCFF5BC37'`

save and run again see if it works now.

Comment: Thanks for reply !! Yes, i am using xcode plugin and using the same command a you mentioned for testing. Problem here is, my test cases are UI test case and when i try to run on simulator it fails. Its because simulator is running on separate thread than the Jenkins.

Comment: I've been having problems with running UI tests myself I havent exactly figured out yet where it goes wrong to be honest.